# Why my app still crashing when internet is off

Tags: android, retrofit, android-permissions, okhttp

My app still crashing when internet is off,
I'm using a module for services thing like Retrofit and OkHttp config, I already add these permissions on manifest on app manifest and on service module manifest but there's no effect.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

But crashilytics is loggin these errors:

```
Fatal Exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "api.com.br": No address associated with hostname
```

---

```
Caused by android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
```

Comment: Without internet connectivity, your DNS lookup of api.com.br will fail.  It'd be best to check for internet connectivity before attempting to do any network calls and show an error to the user instead so that they will know to turn it on in order for your app to work properly.

Comment: @MichaelKrause I thought that it will be enough to prevent crashing my app, how can I handle this on network layer?

Answer (score 1):

The permissions you mentioned are necessary to give your app access to internet, to access network state, and to access wifi state.  However, the user still has the ability to turn on and turn off internet connectivity as they see fit.

Without internet connectivity, your DNS lookup of api.com.br will fail.

You can check for internet connectivity before attempting to do any network calls and show an error to the user instead so that they will know to turn it on in order for your app to work properly.

You can follow Google's Android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-status-type#java) for how to check for internet connectivity.

Essentially:

```
private boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

Additionally, you should plan to catch and handle any network-related exceptions when making network calls and use that to show a useful error to the user.

This is because even with the pre-check for connectivity, there's still a possibility of a network glitch after you've made the call.  The pre-check would prevent you from making a call you know will fail, though.